# Select 2 only working on the first element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have an array and am using select 2 inside that array. Select 2 is working on the first element but in the other elements select 2 is not working.

My html:

```
@foreach($quizzes as $quiz)

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple grades" multiple id="grades" name="grades[]">
<option value="1">Form 1 History</option>
<option value="2">Form 2 History</option>    
</select>
@endforeach
```

My script:

```
 <script>
$("#grades").select2();
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
  if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
    $("#grades > option").prop("selected","selected");// Select All Options
    $("#grades").trigger("change");// Trigger change to select 2
  }
  else{
    $("#grades > option").removeAttr("selected");
    $("#grades").trigger("change");// Trigger change to select 2
  }
});

$("#button").click(function(){
  alert($("#grades").val());
});
$("#grades").select2({
  placeholder: "To be done by...",
  allowClear: true
});

 </script>
```

I can't seem to find out what is wrong.

Comment: i think is because you are using id="grades", try class="grades"

Comment: Yeah that should do it. `id="grades"` to `class="grades"` and `$("#grades").select2();` to `$(".grades").select2();`. The idea of IDs is that they're unique, but you're creating multiple DOMs with same ID. select2 assigns the select2 on the ID and doesn't check for any other elements for same ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing select2 by class name instead of ID. Element IDs should be unique throughout the DOM.

```
$(".grades").select2({
  placeholder: "To be done by...",
  allowClear: true
});
```

And remove the first `$("#grades").select2();`

Comment: In some latest versions of select2 this function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

## id attribute are duplicated

The problem is that the **id** attribute are duplicated.